# React-snap faild in postbulid when uploading to AWS Amplify

Tags: amazon-web-services, puppeteer, aws-amplify, react-snap, aws-cloudshell

I`ve pushed my react project to **AWS amplify** with git. I installed the **react-snap** package for SEO reasons. When inspecting the **Amplify Console**, it shows that the provision step succeeded, but the **building step failed**. The error log shows this:[image: Error log downloaded from AWS]

Some older post on github describe the same problem that I have:
https://github.com/thinkJin6/BokuNews/issues/64

 I have tried out several things like adding and configuring amplify.yml file and configuring the package.json as described here:[image: configuartion of amplify.yml for react-snap]. https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/765
Finally I tried out some stuff from this link: https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/troubleshooting.md#running-puppeteer-on-aws-ec2-instance-running-amazon-linux 
 I enable amazon-linux-extras like this,  **sudo amazon-linux-extras install epel -y**, and installed  install Chromium like this, **sudo yum install -y chromium**.I used **AWS CloudShell**, but the error log message keeps the same.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem recently and with help of a colleague, the solution was found here: [LINK](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/765#issuecomment-445334163)

I added the following to my package.json

```
   "reactSnap": {
    "puppeteerArgs": [
      "--no-sandbox",
      "--disable-setuid-sandbox"
    ],
       "puppeteerExecutablePath": "/opt/google/chrome/google-chrome"
    }
```

Then I updated amplify.yml in was amplify build settings like so

```
version: 1
frontend:
  phases:
    preBuild:
      commands:
        - '# This installs Chrome on any RHEL/CentOS/Amazon Linux variant.'
        - curl https://intoli.com/install-google-chrome.sh | bash
        - npm i
    build:
      commands:
        - npm run build
  artifacts:
    baseDirectory: build
    files:
      - '**/*'
  cache:
    paths:
      - node_modules/**/*
```